# Not able to Import in NLTK - Python

Tags: python, nltk

When I run this command in a file or in a shell

```
import nltk
```

I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from collocations import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 37, in <module>
    from nltk.probability import FreqDist
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 45, in <module>
    import random
  File "random.py", line 2, in <module>
    T = int(raw_input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Not able to comprehend what is going wrong.

Comment: do you have a file named `random.py` ? Change its name to something else and then run. It is overwriting the random method used by nltk.

Comment: Yes thank you! That was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a local `random` module, which masks the `random` module from standard library.

If you try to `import nltk` from a different working directory, it should succeed. But in general it's not a good idea name your modules after standard modules, so please rename your `random.py` file to something else.

You for completeness, let me say that the error was obvious from the last lines of you traceback:

```
  File "random.py", line 2, in <module>
    T = int(raw_input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

From the path, `random.py`, you can tell that the error is in a local file named *random.py*. And from the exception, you know that *something* passed an empty string, `''`, from `raw_input` to `int` function, which failed to be converted to `int`.

*Rule of thumb number 2*: Always guard you executable code, in a module, in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.